# my first jquery - where do I start for rotating image on main page?

Tags: jquery

I've read "jquery fundamentals" which appears a popular recommendation for starting o jquery. I'm also an amateur but reasonably comfortable user of html and css. I have gone to the jquery page and was expecting I'd find a plug in for a changing image but the site says that this section is being redeveloped.

Where should I start? What methods should I consider? As a complete newbie to JS and jquery should I attempt to do this myself or adjust somebody else's work initially?

I'm building a simple website where the home page has a main image that needs to change every few seconds to show a total of about 4 or 5 images.

Someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: i think what your asking about is whats called a Slider. search google for 'jquery image slider' and you can find a plugin to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a plugin, but want to mess around with some code to actually learn something, than this might help you. Just substitute `'.home-page-images'` with your image selector and see the magic happen - the images will change every 5 seconds and will fadeIn in 1 second:

```
$(function(){

var elements = $('.home-page-images');
var counter = 0;

if( elements.length > 1 ){
    elements.hide();
    elements.first().show();
    setInterval(function() {
        elements.eq(counter).fadeOut('slow');
         counter++;
         if (counter == elements.length) {
             counter = 0;
         }
        elements.eq(counter).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 5000);
}
})
```

Mind you, for this to work you will have to output all of your images, position them over one another using CSS. Then JS will take care of the rest.

Also, this will help you to understand how `setInterval` works:
http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: Minor notes: `$(elements)` should be just `elements`. You should not declare a `var` in an if statement, put it with the `elements` declaration.

Comment: Updated the code. As for selectors like `$(elements[counter])`, then my guess is they need to be wrapped in `$(.....)`, since elements[0] would not return a jQuery object? Let me know if I'm wrong though :)

Comment: @leo thanks for the code. I'm in two minds I guess, I certainly wouldlike to learn and become more comfortable with code. I may try this to see what it's like

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. Let me know if it works as you expect it to.

Comment: @leo You are correct, but instead use `elements.first()` and `elements.eq(counter)`. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: @Znarkus Updated, thanks! Didn't know about the `.first()` selector.

Comment: I have done everything correct as far as I can tell but no joy. I created a div to hold the images and have thus changed the following: var elements = $('.home-page-images'); to var elements = $('.slider img');. Is there anything wrong with this selector? Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Nq9/

Comment: The CSS might need to be updated, it doesn't seem to be correct. But the problem with that JSFiddle is that jQuery is not being loaded. Once it's added, the Javascript runs correctly.